# exception occurs while adding array values using "for loop"

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have some code here

```
 String array[]=new String[5];
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        array[i]= "item "+String.valueOf(i);
        i++;
    }
```

and this is log message what i got after application crash

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException : Invalid array range: 5 to 5
```

Could you guys explain me why pls ? I just want to declare an array and use for loop to initialize array element, just dont know why my code didn't work . Thank you

Comment: You have two `i++`. Why?

Comment: oh thank you , my very stupid mistake

Answer (score 3):

because key index More increases than index array in your loop .

```
String array[]=new String[5];
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        array[i]= "item "+String.valueOf(i);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

remove extra i++.. it already redundant except you have some purpose to do so.

```
String array[]=new String[5];
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        array[i]= "item "+String.valueOf(i);
        //i++; //remove this.. it already redundant except you have some purpose
}
```

its `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException : Invalid array range: 5 to 5` because of the counter already exceed size of your string which 5 only..

use `ArrayList` instead

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
String array[]=new String[5];
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    array[i]= "item "+String.valueOf(i);
}
```

That second i++ was causing your index out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Don't increment the 'i' value twice, which is causing this issue.

```
String array[]=new String[5];
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        array[i]= "item "+String.valueOf(i);
        //i++; //remove this..
}
```

Instead of using `Array[]` you can you `Collections` such as `ArrayList<String>` or `List<String>`.